# iOS UI Testing cannot see the UILabel

Tags: xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I have a UI testing issue with some code I've got from another developer (Whose not with the project anymore). The code display a simple alert box at the top of the screen when there's an error and I cannot get my UI test to see the `UILabel` within it.

The structure of the box looks like this:

```
UIView
   + UILabel
   + UIButton
```

And in the custom class for the `UIView` there is this code:

```swift
// Original code
accessibilityIdentifier = "AlertBar" // Required for UI Testing.

// Bits I've added trying to make messageLabel visible to UI Test
isAccessibilityElement = true
accessibilityElements = [messageLabel]
messageLabel.accessibilityIdentifier = "AlertBarMessage"
messageLabel.isAccessibilityElement = true
}
```

If I breakpoint in the middle of my UI Test and dump the app into the log I can see the `UIView`:

```
Attributes: Application, pid: 60317, label: 'The App'
Element subtree:
 →Application, 0x600001df8c40, pid: 60317, label: 'The App'
    Window (Main), 0x600001dfa060, {{0.0, 0.0}, {390.0, 844.0}}

    ... app ui logged here!

      Other, 0x600001dce220, {{4.0, 47.0}, {382.0, 107.7}}, identifier: 'AlertBar'
```

So it's clear that the alert is visible to XCTest, but nothing inside it. As you can tell from my added code I've been trying all sorts of things but so far I've not been able to make the `UILabel` (AlertBarMessage) visible.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per usual, after typing up a stackOVerFlow question I go back to the code and figure out the problem :-) In this case it was the `isAccessibilityElement = true` on the view. Making it accessible was effectively hiding the nested `UILabel` so turning it off fixed my test.

I know there are ways in Accessibility to setup the view correctly for accessibility so that screen readers see it as a single element and can read the message, but I'll have to work on that later for now.